# Scrapy handling multiple spider data processing with items and item loaders

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a big project with too many spiders and I do data processing in my robots instead of using `items` and `item-loaders` and I want to refactor the entire project robots and allocate data processing in items but the problem is I want to update my robots regularly and every website I crawl is different from another, so the data processing is different too, and if I want to implement my data processing in items there will have to be lots of functions and it will cost me a lot in the future so I'm looking for a best practice way to do my data processing somewhere else.
Also, the database is in the robot files and it would be perfect to remove them too.
any suggestion would mean a lot.

> sample, robot

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import SampleScraper
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class sample(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sample"
    start_urls = [
        ""
    ]


    def parse(self, response):

        item_loader = ItemLoader(item = SampleScraper(), selector=response)

        item_loader.add_xpath('title', "//meta[@property='og:title']/@content")
        item_loader.add_xpath('price', "//div[@class='product-info-buy p-15']/div[@class='product-price-wrap']/h5[@class='product-price']/span[@ng-bind='getPrice()|number']/text()")


        yield item_loader.load_item()
```

> sample, items

```
# Define here the models for your scraped items
# See documentation in:
# https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from w3lib.html import remove_tags



def remove_t(value):
    return value.replace('\t', '')


def replacing(value):
    return value.replace(',', '')


class SampleScraper(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:

    title = scrapy.Field(input_processor = MapCompose(remove_tags, remove_t), output_processor = TakeFirst())
    price = scrapy.Field(input_processor = MapCompose(remove_tags, replacing), output_processor = TakeFirst())
```

Answer (score 1):

A much better practice for a project with many spiders, would be to create a base item class and base item loader `BaseItemLoader` with common fields and processors used in all projects, and for each project, you'd create custom item loaders that extends `BaseItemLoader`, so you can have your custom field processors there for each project.

Let's say `title` field and its input processor would be common to all projects, while all the other input/output processors and fields would be specific for each project - e.g. sample spider from your example.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from w3lib.html import remove_tags


def remove_t(value):
    return value.replace('\t', '')


def replacing(value):
    return value.replace(',', '')


class BaseItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    

class BaseItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = BaseItem
    title_in = MapCompose(remove_tags, remove_t)

----

class SampleScraper(BaseItem):
    price = scrapy.Field()


class SampleItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = SampleScraper
    title_out = TakeFirst()
    price_in = MapCompose(remove_tags, replacing)
    price_out = TakeFirst()
```

Then in your sample spider code, you'd just call the item loader:

```
...
def parse(self, response):

    item_loader = SampleItemLoader(selector=response)
    item_loader.add_xpath('title', "//meta[@property='og:title']/@content")
    item_loader.add_xpath('price', "//div[@class='product-info-buy p-15']/div[@class='product-price-wrap']/h5[@class='product-price']/span[@ng-bind='getPrice()|number']/text()")

    yield item_loader.load_item()
```